# Selenium does not execute click command

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-ide

I had an HTML button with id=submit so using Selenium IDE I selected the command "Click" with target as id=submit but selenium IDE pass this line as if it is executed but without the button really clicked so the form is not submitted !! what is wrong ?

Here is the C# code I exported. Problem is in `driver.FindElement(By.Name("submit")).Click();`

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace SeleniumTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Web
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;
        private StringBuilder verificationErrors;
        private string baseURL;
        private bool acceptNextAlert = true;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetupTest()
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            baseURL = "I cannot share url";
            verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TeardownTest()
        {
            try
            {
                driver.Quit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
            }
            Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
        }

        [Test]
        public void TheWebTest()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("I cannot share url");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("submit")).Click();
            for (int second = 0;; second++) {
                if (second >= 60) Assert.Fail("timeout");
                try
                {
                    if ("All Campaigns" == driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#CampaignsTable > div.box > div.title")).Text) break;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {}
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            for (int second = 0;; second++) {
                if (second >= 60) Assert.Fail("timeout");
                try
                {
                    if ("Last" == driver.FindElement(By.Id("cloaker_last")).Text) break;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {}
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//img[@alt='Click to edit the rotator settings'])[1]")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("addNewUrl_0_geo_0_url_to_cloak")).Clear();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("addNewUrl_0_geo_0_url_to_cloak")).SendKeys("dghfghf");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("addNewUrl_0_geo_0_mobile_url")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("submit")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("submit")).Click();
            for (int second = 0;; second++) {
                if (second >= 60) Assert.Fail("timeout");
                try
                {
                    if ("Success" == driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.message.green > span > b")).Text) break;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {}
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//img[@alt='Click to edit the rotator settings'])[2]")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("addNewUrl_0_geo_0_url_to_cloak")).Clear();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("addNewUrl_0_geo_0_url_to_cloak")).SendKeys("tyujghghj");
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("submit")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//img[@alt='Click to edit the rotator settings'])[3]")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("addNewUrl_0_geo_0_url_to_cloak")).Clear();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("addNewUrl_0_geo_0_url_to_cloak")).SendKeys("gfhjghjgh");
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("submit")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//img[@alt='Click to edit the rotator settings'])[4]")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("addNewUrl_0_geo_0_url_to_cloak")).Clear();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("addNewUrl_0_geo_0_url_to_cloak")).SendKeys("ghghkghk");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("addNewUrl_0_geo_0_mobile_url")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("submit")).Click();
        }
        private bool IsElementPresent(By by)
        {
            try
            {
                driver.FindElement(by);
                return true;
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private bool IsAlertPresent()
        {
            try
            {
                driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
                return true;
            }
            catch (NoAlertPresentException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private string CloseAlertAndGetItsText() {
            try {
                IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
                string alertText = alert.Text;
                if (acceptNextAlert) {
                    alert.Accept();
                } else {
                    alert.Dismiss();
                }
                return alertText;
            } finally {
                acceptNextAlert = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you shared existing code, the URL you are trying to reference, etc. we could be more helpful.

It's very hard to answer a question without enough information.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared the code so It is hard to analyze your problem. This might help you -

just change your command `click` to `clickAt` and then try.

Comment: same problem, I use the IDE